# Install Crypt::SSLeay Debian

Tags: debian, perl

Crypt::SSLeay

In debian? What's the command.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can install Crypt:SSLeay on Debian using the following command:;;

`sudo apt-get install libcrypt-ssleay-perl`

Comment: Thank you so much, i spent hours trying to install this module ...

Answer (score 2):

Give this a try:

```
cpan Crypt::SSLeay
```

Comment: You'll want to install `libssl-dev` before.